# Django display table in templates

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 2.0.1, and I have the following code:

```
Models.py:
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class CategoryItems(models.Model):
    category_name = = models.ForeignKey(Categories, related_name='categoriesfk', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Thereafter my views.py:

```
def data(request):
    categories_query = Categories.objects.all()
    category_items_query = CategoriesItems.objects.all()

return render_to_response("data.html", 
{'categories_query': categories_query,'category_items_query': category_items_query}
```

In the template I'm trying to display all items for each category, for example, suppose there are 4 categorizes, e.g. Bicycle, then it display all items belonging to that category only. For example, as follows:

**Category 1:**
Category_Item 1,
Category_Item 2,
Category_Item 3, 
and so on ...

**Category 2:**
Category_Item 1,
Category_Item 2,
Category_Item 3, 
and so on ...

I have tried to write so many different for-loops, but they just display all items, I need it to show items only for that category, then for loop to next category and show items for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need your `category_items_query` variable, just `category_query`:

```
{% for category in category_query %}
    <b>{{ category.category_name }}</b><br />
    {% for item in category.categoriesfk.all %}
        {{ item.item_name }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Your `related_name` of `categoriesfk` is weird, it'd make more sense to be something like `items`.

Comment: Fantastic! So clean!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is two for loops with an if to check if the second loop should belong to the first.
Try this:

```
{% for category in categories_query %}
  {% for category_item in category_items_query %}
    {% if category_item.category_name == category %}
      {# do something with category_item #}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I believe it would be more clear if you named the ForeignKey in CategoryItems to just "category", instead of "category_name", since this field will have the category itself, not just it's name. Your "if" would then be more readable and make more sense:

```
{% if category_item.category == category %}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A few things,

1. Since your model name is already Category, your field names should be like `name` instead of `category_name`.
2. Model names must be singular, so it should be`CategoryItem` instead of `CategoryItems`
3. When you do a `model_name.objects.all()`, you do not get a query but a `Queryset`, make your variable names such that they describe what they do. Currently, `categories_query` is wrong. You could instead use `category_qs`.

Now, coming to your question, you require two for loops. One to loop through the categories and then one to loop through items in a particular category.

Something like,

```
for category in category_qs:
    for item in category:
        # Do something with item
```

You have the basic idea here, now you can convert it to real working code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Grouping data in template is not best idea as template should be logic free, 
also good idea would be to use database capabilities and use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to query out related set

```
category_data = Category.objects.select_related('item').all()
```

afterwards you could do following in template

```
{% for category in category_data %}
  {# print category #}
  {% for item in category.items %}
      {# print item #}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Django has a built-in [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag for this functionality.

```
{% regroup category_items_query by category_name as categoryname_list %}

{% for category in categoryname_list %}
    <strong>{{ category.grouper }}</strong><br>
    {% for item in category.list %}
        {{ item.item_name }}: {{ item.item_description }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You have to order your CategoryItems for this functionality to work.

```
category_items_query = CategoriesItems.objects.all().order_by('category_name')
```