# Django template display first 3 related to that category

Tags: python, django

In reference to this model: [My Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586295/django-display-table-in-templates/48597862)

In the template - I want to show the first three items in one column / for loop, then another 3 in another column / for loop, e.g.

```
  Category 1
Item 1   Item 4
Item 2   Item 5
Item 3   Item 6
```

I tried using slices, but that only retrieves the first three in the object, so if the first two item belongs to Category 1, and the last item belongs to Category 2, it only show 2 items. I want to grab first 3 items for each category, then vice versa, last three items. Is this feasible in the for loop?

Comment: Are you asking about how to render this in HTML? It seems like you're asking about the layout of items on your template, which is a problem that should be solved with a CSS framework, or a tool like CSS Flexbox rather than Django.

Comment: Can I not specify on for loop to show first three items related to that category in django?

Comment: You can add one more context key and slice your query set fetched data you will get two lists than you can iterate

Comment: @BalarajuM what you mean in the for loop? I have at least 5 categories, so I'm trying to do it as dynamically as possible, instead of statically.

Answer (score 11):

This was the solution:

```
{% for item in category.categoriesfk.all|slice:"0:3" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this must work:

{% for item in category.all|slice:"0:3" %}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).